# Is the source (and/or target) a group, or just its underlying set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Consider the following statements.

- Let $G$ and $H$ denote groups and $f : G \rightarrow H$ denote an arbitrary function.
- Let $G$ and $H$ denote groups and $f : G \rightarrow H$ denote an arbitrary homomorphism.

What are these statements really saying? Are the source and target of $f$

1. the *groups* $G$ and $H$, or
2. just their underlying sets?

---

A review of the usual definitions.

**Definition 1.** A *function* is an ordered triple $(X,Y,f)$ satisfying

$$\forall x \in X \exists! y \in Y : (x,y) \in f.$$

We write $f : X \rightarrow Y$.

**Definition 2.** A *group* is an ordered pair $(X,*)$ satisfying the familiar group axioms. Call $X$ the *underlying set* of $(X,*)$.

Comment: The second. ${}{}$

Comment: For the edited question: option 1. That is, the function preserves the structure of the groupe ($g_1\cdot_G g_2=g\Rightarrow f(g_1)\cdot_H f(g_2)=f(g)$, etc)

Answer (score 1):

$G$ and $H$ certainly can be groups, but the function will not necessarily preserve any structure, so it will just be a map between sets.

If $f$ is a homomorphism, this preserves structure by definition, so it will be a map between groups by necessity.

Comment: I think he distinguishes groups and underlying sets meaning that the first is the ordered pair; thus even in the case of group morphism the map has still their underlying sets as source and target.